# How can I wait for BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, synchronization, backgroundworker

I have a method `Foo()`, which creates and runs a `BackgroundWorker`.
`RunWorkerCompleted`, `ProgressChanged` etc. are handled inside `Foo()`.

My main thread calls `MyObject.Foo()`.
Right after calling `MyObject.Foo()` main thread calls `MyObject.DoSthWithFooData()`.

Main Thread doesn't know anything about the `BackgroundWorker` inside `MyObject.Foo()`.

How can I force main thread to wait until `BackgroundWorker` has finished its work?

`DoSthWithFooData()` must be called when the `BackgroundWorker` in `MyObject.Foo()` has finished its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. You can remove the `BackgroundWorker` entirely and just execute your code synchronously. If you're going to force the code to wait on the `BackgroundWorker` to finish anyway, then that's essentially what you're doing. This is not the best option, assuming that the next is practical for you.
2. Move the logic that would ordinarily follow the call to `MyObject.Foo()` into the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. This is preferred, as it will maintain the "background" element of the work and the UI will remain responsive.

Comment: I decided to remove the backgroundworker for this case. It's a cleaner solution. GUI with BGW console without

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the main thread to wait for the BackgroundWorker. That would cause your GUI to become unresponsive - not a good user experience. The whole point of using the BackgroundWorker in the first place is to avoid blocking the main thread. Instead you should register an event handler for the background worker's [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event. The code in the event handler will be run when the background task completes.

If you want to prevent users from interacting with the program while the background task is  running then:

- Disable the relevant controls when you start the BackgroundWorker.
- Re-enable them again in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My Application has the ability to run in console mode. When foo() is called it has no user interface!

Answer (score 2):

put the `DoSthWithFooData` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` Event

Comment: No I can't. I need to call it from outside.

Comment: I mean. I can't call DoSthWithFooData() inside RunworkerCompleted.

Answer (score 0):

Give Foo() a parameter a callbacb Action delegate that is called when foo is done
And then you can Use MenualResetEvent to wait for Foo to finish.

when Action delegate is called signal ManualReset event